# How to respond to a limitless possibility of outcomes?

Tags: c++

So let's say that there is an imaginary 2 by 2 grid comprised for 4 numbers ...

```
1 2
3 4
```

You can either flip the grid horizontally or vertically down the middle by imputing either `H` or `V` respectively. You can also flip the grid as many times as you wish, with the previous choice affecting your future outcome.

For example, you could flip the grid horizontally down the middle, and then vertically.

While solving this problem, I got enough code written down so that the program works, except for the part where the "flipping" happens. Since you can enter as many `H`'s and `V`'s as you would like, I have some trouble writing code that would support this action.

Since the program input could contain as many horizontal or vertical flips as the user would prefer, that prevents me from manually using if-statements; in other words, I can't say "if the 1st letter is `H`, flip horizontally, if the 2nd letter is `V`, flip vertically, etc.".

This is just a short snippet of what I have figured out so far...

```cpp
void flipGrid(string str, int letterPlace)
{
    while (letterPlace < str.length())
    {
        if (str.at(letterPlace) == 'H')
        {
            // flip grid horizontally
        }
        else if (str.at(letterPlace) == 'V')
        {
            // flip grid vertically
        }

        letterPlace += 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int increment = 0;

    string userInput;
    cin >> userInput;

    flipGrid(userInput, increment);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can probably tell, I need help with the parts specified by the comments. If the code were to run as planned, it should look something like this...

Input (example 1)

```
H
```

Output

```
3 4
1 2
```

---

Input (example 2)

```
HVVH
```

Output (the two H's and the two V's cancel out, leaving us with the original)

```
1 2
3 4
```

I feel like there should be an easier way to solve this problem, or is the method I'm currently working on the right way to approach this problem? Please let me know if I'm on the right track or not. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there are no more than 24 possible outcomes (4*3*2*1), although there are "limitless" ways to get to them.  (Actually, given the limited number & type of moves, there are only 4.)

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes that's what I meant. I couldn't think of a better title though. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be easy if the numbers were in a "2d array", like `int grid[2][2]`. Then you could just swap e.g. `grip[0][0]` with `grid[1][0]` and `grip[0][1]` with `grid[1][1]` for a horizontal flip. For dynamic sizes and (for horizontal flips) you could use `std::vector`.

Comment: What exactly do you think is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Well, I think I'm doing everything else right, but just don't know what do do with the if-statements.

Comment: @FuzzySquid Are you saying you don't know how to properly flip it in the each statement, or you feel you shouldn't need the if statements?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Are you suggesting that I swap the grids be in a while loop?

Comment: @Chipster I don't know how to flip it in each statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a few things. First, I would simply count the H's and V's and, when done, modulo 2 each count. This will leave you flipCountH and flipCountV each having 0 or 1. There's no need to do multiple flips, right? Then you'll at most do each action once.

```
void flipCounts(string str, int &flipCountH, int &flipCountY)
{
    for (char c: str) {
        if (c == 'H')
        {
            ++flipCountH;
        }
        else if (c == 'V')
        {
            ++clipCountY
        }
    }
}
```

Use that method, then:

```
flipCountH %= 2;
flipCountY %= 2;
if (flipCountH > 0) {
    performHorizontalFlip();
}
if (flipCountV > 0) {
    performVerticalFlip();
}
```

Now, HOW you flip is based on how you store the data. For this very specific problem, I would store it in an int[2][2].

```
void performVerticalFlip() {
    int[2] topLine;
    topLine[0] = grid[0][0];
    topLine[1] = grid[0][1];

    grid[0][0] = grid[1][0];
    grid[0][1] = grid[1][1];
    grid[1][0] = topLine[0];
    grid[1][1] = topLine[1];
}
```

Now, you can probably make use of C++ move semantics, but that's an advanced topic. You could also make a swap method that swaps two integers. That's not so advanced.

```
void swap(int &a, int &b) {
   int tmp = a;
   a = b;
   b = tmp;
}
```

Then the code above is simpler:
    swap(grid[0][0], grid[1][0]);
    swap(grid[0][1], grid[1][1]);

Horizontal flip is similar.

Comment: Just to get this right, so you're playing with the fact that an even number of H's cancel out?

Comment: @FuzzySquid that is correct. Flipping twice in either direction is equivalent to not flipping at all. You only care if there are an odd number of flips.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> I don't know how to flip it in each statement

So, flipping a 2x2 grid vertically is simple:

```
int tmp = grid[0][0];
grid[0][0] = grid[1][0];
grid[1][0] = tmp;

tmp = grid[0][1];
grid[0][1] = grid[1][1];
grid[1][1] = tmp;
```

If you have a grid bigger than a 2x2, this will work as well:

```
// for half the height of the grid
for(unsigned int i = 0;i<Height/2;i++) {
    // for the width of the grid
    for(unsigned int j =0; j<Width) {

        // store a copy of the old value
        int tmp = grid[i][j];
        // put the new value in
        grid[i][j] = grid[Height-1-i][j]; // note, we are flipping this vertically,
                                          // so we want something an equal distance away
                                          // from the other end as us
        // replace the value we were grabbing from with the saved value
        grid[Height-1-i][j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

In case this is homework, I'm going to leave a horizontal flip for you to figure out (hint, it's the same thing, but with the width and height reversed).